# New control in Form from another Class

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have a class in the same file as the Form1 : Form class (directly proceeding) and would like to create a new control (label thisObj = new label();) from within the class. I tried to use the following code:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
label thisObj = new label();
thisObj.Name = "One";
form.Controls.Add(thisObj);
```

However, when I do this, the form window doesn't load when starting the debugging.

EDIT: The line **"Form1 form = new Form1()"** causes the form not to load.

Comment: `Form1 form = new Form1()` doesn't load the form.  You at least need to call `Show` or `ShowDialog` for that to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by sending an instance of the Form through the constructor of the class.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
this.Controls.Add(thisObj);
```

It will add the control to the current form.

Comment: as you can see in my code, I am already using the Add function.

Answer (score 1):

To just add a control to the current Form, the code from Frederick is correct, like this:

```
var thisObj = new Label { Name = "One", Text = "Some Text" };
Controls.Add(thisObj);
```

It is normal that Form1 does not show, you never call the Show() method. If you want to show Form1 with the new Label added this is the code:

```
var form = new Form1();
var thisObj = new Label { Name = "One", Text = "Some Text" };
form.Controls.Add(thisObj);
form.Show();
```

The form that will be loaded by default in your WindowsForms application is defined in the file 'Program.cs':

```
Application.Run(new Form1);
```